# USB OTG with power supply connection to Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: usb, power-supply, pi-zero, usb-power

I have connected my 5.2 V 2 A tablet charger to power USB port of Raspberry Pi Zero and USB port to my Linux OS Lenovo laptop, according to [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58453/pi-zero-otg-with-backup-power) I must cut the 5 V pin of USB PC port, but I didn't do that.

Now when I plug my Pi Zero to my PC via USB port on my Linux it doesn't recognize it as a device, but when I am connecting the [5 inch LCD](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.waveshare.com/5inch-hdmi-lcd.htm&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiD_Z2h4MLiAhXCjqQKHdTVAhIQFjAEegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw36G9xCWN5tJe-DZFE7u567), it's working. I tested my laptop USB port with my mouse and it's working. So I want to know:

1. Have my laptop USB ports been corrupted?
2. If Pi Zero's USB OTG port has been burned, is it possible I fix its USB port or use a USB Wi-Fi dongle to connect to my PC?

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way for us to know from the information provided.  I suggest you plug in another known to work device.  If that works then the ports are okay.

2) If USB is broken there is no repair possible for less than the cost of a new Pi.

Comment: I will test my pi zero to another pc as soon as possible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will check my pi to new laptop soon.